# From SELECT to UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I would like you to help me with this, I have a little problem with this, but I don't know how I can fix it, basically I want to update the so called duplicatedusernameid, and update it into the users database. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE users SET duplicatedusernameid = (SELECT CONCAT(first_name,middle_name,last_name)
,COUNT(*)-1 AS duplicatedusernameid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) WHERE id = 1
```

And here is the working SELECT function, but instead of select I want UPDATE, like the one above, but that one doesn't work. Here is the SELECT code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,middle_name,last_name),COUNT(*)-1 AS duplicatedusernameid 
FROM users HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

So basically I want to get the value of the duplicatedusernameid and update it.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?

Comment: @David Okay, basically what it does it gets the first, middle and last name and it get the duplicates (how many people have the same name), then I would like to update it into the users table and we get the value of how many have the same name. BTW this system above can actually differentiate and if the user dosn't have a middle name, it will just be blank and only get the value of first name and last name and then it will check how many have the same name. Does that make sense?

Comment: do you want to UPDATE **all** duplicates or only **a specific one** ? In you `SELECT` statement you don't specify a `WHERE` clause and in your `UPDATE` statement you have `WHERE id = 1` so it is confusing. Rephrase all this correctly please, and when you have an error it's always a good idea to add the error message to the question.

Comment: @AllanVester: That doesn't really describe in what way this code is failing.  What does that `SELECT` return?  If it's anything more than a single scalar value then I'm not sure what that `UPDATE` is really expected to do, since you'd be trying to update a single value by using a set of values.  Does this code update anything at all?  Is there an error?  Does the `WHERE` clause find the record(s) you're looking for?

Comment: @ThomasG In the UPDATE section, I actually wanted to use WHERE id = and then something, becasue I'm using Laravel, I can get the users id from the users table, just by doing this simple command. WHERE id = ?", [Auth::user()->id]

Comment: @David I don't really know where the code is failing, but the system I'm trying to build is kinda like Facebooks system. http://i.imgur.com/NFAQ7bL.png , so everytime a user registers, the system will check if a person have the same name as someone else, and then it will put a number at the end. Take me for example, Allan Vester.1 and then another person registers with the name of Allan Vester, and then the system will check again and this time it will be like Allan Vester.2 at the end, since that name have already been taken.

Comment: But what is the point of trying to find the duplicate using `HAVING COUNT` if you already know which row it is (`WHERE id=1`)? I don't see the sense of this

Comment: @David Also when I run the UPDATE query, I get this message sent out from MySQL. #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @AllanVester: Well, that error makes sense to me because the `SELECT` is returning two columns.  So the logic would have no way of knowing which value you want set in the `duplicatedusernameid` column in the `UPDATE` statement.  The `SELECT` should just be returning the single scalar value to put in that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SQL statement like this:

```
update users a
inner join (
  -- get the count for a user
  SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, COUNT(*)-1 AS duplicatedusernameid 
  from users 
  group by first_name, middle_name, last_name
) b 
  on a.first_name = b.first_name
  and a.middle_name = b.middle_name
  and a.last_name = b.last_name
set a.duplicatedusernameid = b.duplicatedusernameid
where a.id = 1;
```

**Table**

```
create table users (
  id int,
  first_name varchar(100),
  middle_name varchar(100),
  last_name varchar(100),
  duplicatedusernameid varchar(100)
);

insert into users  (id, first_name, middle_name, last_name) values
(1, 'John', '', 'Smith'),
(2, 'John', '', 'Smith'),
(3, 'Jessie', '', 'Marcus'),
(4, 'Jessie', '', 'Marcus'),
(5, 'Jessie', '', 'Marcus'),
(6, 'Don', '', 'Kassieth');
```

**Results (if you remove the where clause)**

```
| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | duplicatedusernameid |
|----|------------|-------------|-----------|----------------------|
|  1 |       John |             |     Smith |                    1 |
|  2 |       John |             |     Smith |                    1 |
|  3 |     Jessie |             |    Marcus |                    2 |
|  4 |     Jessie |             |    Marcus |                    2 |
|  5 |     Jessie |             |    Marcus |                    2 |
|  6 |        Don |             |  Kassieth |                    0 |
```

**Explanation**

```
SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, COUNT(*)-1 AS duplicatedusernameid 
from users 
group by first_name, middle_name, last_name
```

The above SQL statement will get the count for each unique first, middle and last name combination. You can shortlist this by adding `having count(*) > 1` below the `group by` clause.

We then join users table with this count-related table based on first, middle and last name combination. Wherever there is a match, update the retrieved count in the users table.

**SQLFiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c43ea/1